# Feathers.js authentication service uses global entity and service variables when constructing the JWT instead of local entity

Tags: typescript, jwt, feathersjs, feathers-authentication, feathers-hook

I am using `feathers.js` for my app. In my app, I use different strategies. For all those strategies the entity is `user`. But I also want to use `local` strategy for internal operators. The global entity is set to `user` but for `local` strategy which I registered under the name of `operator` I set the entity to `operator` (I have `user` and `operator` tables in my Postgres database). This is my `config/default.js`:

```js
}
  ...
  authentication: {
    secret: "JWT_SECRET",
    entity: "user",
    service: "user",
    phone: {
      entity: "user",
      service: "user"
    },
    jwt: {},
    operator: {
      entity: "operator",
      service: "operator",
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password"
    },
    authStrategies: ["jwt", "phone, "operator"],
    ...
}
```

This is my `authentication.ts` file (I omitted some code for brewety):

```js
export default function(app: Application): void {
  authentication.register("phone", new PhoneStrategy());
  authentication.register("jwt", new JwtStrategy());
  authentication.register("operator", new OperatorStrategy());

  app.use("/authentication", authentication);
  app.configure(expressOauth());
}

class OperatorStrategy extends LocalStrategy {
  async authenticate(data: any, params: Params) {
    const operator = await this.app?.service("operator").find({
      query: {
        email: data.email,
        $limit: 1
      }
    });

    if (operator) {
      const encryptedPass = getHash(data.password, operator.id);
      if (operator.password === encryptedPass) {
        const { email, password, ...restOfOperator } = operator;
        return restOfOperator;
      }
    } else {
      throw new NotAuthenticated();
    }
  }
}
```

I have service called `operator` and hooks for this service.

```
const isAuthorized = async (
  context: HookContext
): Promise<HookContext> => {
  console.log("User: ", context.params.user)

  }
  return context;
}

export default {
  before: {
    all: [],
    find: [authenticate("operator"), isAuthorized],
    get: [],
    create: [],
    update: [],
    patch: [],
    remove: []
  },
  ...
}
```

So you can see above I am calling `authenticate("operator")` before `find()` and then I was going to call `isAuthorized` to do some checks. However, `context.params.user` returns `undefined`.

It looks like for some reason the authentication service uses global entity and service variables when constructing the JWT.

Is there something missing in my configuration to make auth service use `operator` entity? Or another words is there a way to use `operator` service for `local` strategy instead of global `user`?

Comment: Not sure if it's because you omitted the code, but the docs suggest a slightly different setup for the auth service (https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/service.html).
Are you defining the auth service with `const authService = new AuthenticationService(app);`  before registering the strategies?

Comment: yes, I have `const authentication = new MyAuthService(app);` before registering the services.